# Footer to Django-base site (using

Tags: html, css, django, footer

I'm trying to use tamplates for the site. I have base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block url %}{% endblock %}
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="{% static "app/css/base.css" %}"/>
</head>
<body link="#FFFFFF" alink="#fefefe" alink="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF">
         <div class="page-wrap">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
        <footer class="site-footer">
            footer information
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

base.css

```
  * {
      margin: 0%;
    }
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .page-wrap {
      min-height: 100%;
      margin-bottom: -100px; 
    }
    .page-wrap:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
    }
    .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
      height: 100px; 
    }
    .site-footer {
      width: 100%;
      background: #222222;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

The footer at the index.html is working correctly, but on the other's html footer is standing under divs, and don't stick to footer. Is it possible to fix it? Thank u!
UPD:
There seems a little bag at the index.

```
    {% extends "app/base.html" %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
            {% block title %}Feedbacker{% endblock %}
            {% block url %}
            {% endblock %}
            {% block content %}
                <div id="content">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <div id="usDescr"> Welcome, {{user.username}} </div>
                    <p class="myBtn"><a href="/my" >My Cab</a></p>
                    {% else %}
                    <header class = "descr">
header information
                    </header>
                    <div class="login-card">
login box
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endif %} 
                {% endblock %}
```

If I'm stay not logged in footer works correctly, but if I log in and content changes to the {% if user.is_authenticated %} footer will leave his palce and stay under div = "Content"

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty small error - I used {% endblock %} on the one up line